# On down vote why my reputation sometime decrease and somtimes not?

Tags: discussion

I Know I will get a **-1 reputation** for downvote, but sometimes I will not get any -1 rep. **On what criteria downvote operate ?** Today I flagged the answer and downvote it and I got a -1 reputation, but before this week I had a same thing but without -1 rep, Please clarify it!!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only down-voting an answer reduces your [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), and only when the answer is not a CW ([*Community Wiki*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)). Down-voting a question, or a CW answer doesn't give you any -1.

Keep in mind that a [vote is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits) after X minutes you cast it. If you try to down-vote a post that you already up-voted earlier, the down-vote is not recorded, and you don't get any -1.